# Ionic 2 / Angular issue with http post to laravel api

Tags: angular, laravel, http, ionic2, cors

I am finding it difficult to send http post request to laravel api.
GET method is just working fine but I get below error in google chrome console

> Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/user/auth: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

It is been 2 days since i am searching for solution.
I found a post on ionic official blog here https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/
but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks

Here is my code

```
authUser(email, pass) {       
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    let data = JSON.stringify(
      {
        "email": email,
        "password": pass
      }
    );
    this.http.post(this.API_URL+'user/auth', data, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      if(data['success']) {
        this.user = data['response'];
      } else {
        this.hasError = data['message'];
        console.log(this.hasError);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: enable **CORS** on your API server https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Thanks @TiepPhan, but I already had cors middleware setup in laravel, and my GET request are working fine

Comment: according your error message above, your server doesn’t set up correctly to accept Origin localhost:8100. please verify your server to accept the Origin above.

Comment: Thanks @TiepPhan for the help, I will try your solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the solution
I have changed Content-Type: application/json and the data body, below is the example

```
authUser(email, pass) {       
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' //updated
      })
    };
    let data = "email="+email+"&password="+pass+""; //updated

    this.http.post(this.API_URL+'user/auth', data, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      if(data['success']) {
        this.user = data['response'];
        console.log(this.user);
      } else {
        this.hasError = data['message'];
        console.log(this.hasError);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: you save my day. thanks. when i google for how to call a post method in laravel by ionic3 i found nothing . my content type json and cors error kill me. but you survive me thanks

Comment: what about when if i use bearer token and want to add Authorization to this andthen i have  CORS error

Comment: @KhanSahrukh yes of course this is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56157129/308578